# Flagging Innapropriate HTML Heading Structure with CSS or jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, node.js, accessibility, cheerio

I'm currently developing a script that will scan HTML files and flag any potential accessibility issues.  One of the more common problems that I would like to address is heading structure -- when content creators skipped from h1 to h3, h2 to h4, etc.

I'm working with CSS and Cheerio (a Node.js implementation of the jQuery library).  The best solution is something along the lines of:

```
var cheerio = require("cheerio"),
    fs = require("fs");

var badHeadings = [];
var $temp = cheerio.load(fs.readFileSync("./file.html")

$temp("*:not('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6').remove();
$temp("h1 + h3, h2 + h4, h3 + h5, h4 + h6").each(function(){
    badHeadings.push($(this).html());
});
// Next use badHeadings array to search on a new cheerio instance of the same file.
```

The fact that Cheerio has limited support for the ':contains' selector (and spotty support for the ':not' selector) which means this approach is probably not ideal.

Can anyone think of an easier/better way?  Some mind-bending combination of css selectors would even be welcome, but I don't know if that's possible.

Comment: I would go after a real-life solution first to be honest. Most of the time when I tell people what headings are, what they do, and how to use them, results are usually better than anything automatic

Comment: I'm already on that, unfortunately, there's an entire legacy of HTML that used headings for style rather than structure.  Hundreds if not thousands of pages...

Answer (score 0):

> there's an entire legacy of HTML that used headings for style rather than structure. Hundreds if not thousands of pages

Where I work we take three approaches.  It may not help your exact question, but it may change your mindset from *"everything must be accessible"* to risk-based.

1. if it is current stuff, and will be updated in the next cycle or pushed to a new template, it must be formatted correctly by the author before it goes live. If not it should be fixed when it can, i.e., use analytics to figure out if these things are actually being used
2. if it is newly developed stuff must adhere to the standards, or the content won't go live, period.
3. if the content is truly legacy, stuff from 10+ years ago, that nobody except a few who refer to it once in a blue moon, we have a legacy/archive policy that says this content is up for historical purposes, it will never be updated, use at your own risk. Of course we provide a POC just in case somebody does need the content.

Comment: Thank you for the reply Ryan.  In my context, virtually everything is current.  I work for a college and the HTML files sit inside a Learning Management System.  Content has been developed for a few years without a real understanding of accessibility concerns.